# Are there random thermal motions in a streamline flow?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Because the presence of pressure in all directions also demands the presence of random thermal motions. And then in the presence of random thermal motions how do you define a streamline? I mean how can you merge the two(a random motion and a steady motion) to explain the net result? What does the velocity at a point in a streamline really mean when there is such thermal randomization actually present?

Answer (score 2):

Random thermal fluctuations do exist at every point in the flow, and in fact, they can be quite important to model when trying to capture transition to turbulence in things like hypersonic boundary layers.

However, the streamlines are generally calculated using the continuum velocity, which means it is based on the bulk motion of a small "fluid packet." The packet is averaged over an infinitesimal region of space, but the region is large enough (or the gas dense enough) that it has a huge number of molecules inside the region. This means from a continuum perspective, the random thermal motions all average out to zero and the only motions are bulk motions.

So, from a traditional fluid dynamics standpoint, streamlines are unaware of thermal motions and they don't need to be aware of them either. The velocity of the fluid is based on coherent motion only.

Comment: Thanks Friend...

Comment: I have another question... Besides velocity, can the shape of the tube through which the liquid is flowing determine if the flow will be laminar or turbulent. I mean what about a highly random and asymmetric tube. Will it allow for laminar flow...?

Comment: @user266637 If you have another question, you'll need to post it as a new question instead of asking in the comments here (after searching to see if there are existing questions that will answer it for you)!

Comment: Ok I will do it